# Orthosymplectic superalgebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, lie-superalgebras

Let $V=V_0 \oplus V_1$ be a $\mathbb Z_2$-graded vector space over $\mathbb C$. Suppose $V$ has an even non-degenerate bilinear form $(-, -)$
which is symmetric on $V_0$, skew symmetric on $V_1$, and satisfies
$(V_0, V_1) = (V_1, V_0) = 0$.

Let $\dim(V_0)=m$ and $\dim(V_1)=2n$. Then the orthosymplectic Lie superalgebra $\mathfrak{osp}(m,2n)$ (or $\mathfrak{osp}(V)$) is the $\mathbb Z_2$-graded subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(m,2n)$ defined by $\{X \in \mathfrak{gl}(m,2n): (Xv,w)+(-1)^{\lvert X\rvert\lvert v\rvert}(v,Xw)=0\}$. It is the Lie algebra corresponding to the orthosymplectic supergroup $\operatorname{OSp}(V)$.

My question is as the adjoint representation of $\operatorname{OSp}(V)$, what is $\mathfrak{osp}(m,2n)$ isomorphic to ?

The adjoint action of the usual orthogonal group $O(W)$ on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(W)$ corresponds to the standard action of $O(W)$ on $\bigwedge^2 W$ and we have $\mathfrak{so}(W)\cong \bigwedge^2 W$. But in the super case $\dim(\mathfrak{osp}(V)) > \dim(\bigwedge^2 V)$.